# Use java library from python (Python wrapper for java library)

Tags: java, python

I have a java library in jar form which can be used to extract data from files(excel,xml etc). As its in java, it can be used only in java applications. But i need the same library to be used for python projects as well. 
I have tried py4j etc which takes the objects from jvm. But the library is not an executable and wont be 'run'. I have checked Jython but i need the library to be accessible from Python projects.
I have thought about using automated java to python translators, but i would take that as the last resort.

Please suggest some way i can accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a one class java program with a thread never ending until you send from Python a notification to do so.

This way the lib would be kept in memory and accessible from your Python program.

This class could be like this (add your needed lib import/init) :

```
public class TestPy {

    private Thread thread;

    public void die() {
        synchronized (thread) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }    
    }

    public TestPy() {
        thread = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPy tp = new TestPy();
        GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(tp);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

You would have to launch the java program, use the lib, and then use the die() method to kill the java program in Python :

```
gateway = JavaGateway()
do your stuff here using the lib
tp = gateway.entry_point
tp.die()
```

Comment: is there no other way other than loading the library to jvm?

Comment: Py4J doesn't contain a JVM, so you must have one living (hence the java program) to let Py4J access the library.

Comment: I can start the java code from python, but how will i get the handle to call TestPy.die() after everything is done? Please clarify

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple command line Java program which calls the library and saves the results in a format you can read in Python, then you can call the program from Python using `os.system`.

Another option is to find Python libraries with equivalent functionality to the Java library: you can read excel, xml and other files in Python, that's not a problem.

Comment: im sorry,i didnt understand what you meant by 'calls the library and saves the results'. Did you mean serialization? But its a library, which needs several parameters to get the returned object. 
As for the second suggestion, i was trying to see if there was an easier way to do the task (instead of the rework)

Comment: No, I didn't mean serialization. You could save the result (the 'extracted data', as you wrote about it) in a format like CSV, JASON, XML or something like that), something you can read easily in Python.

Comment: Regarding your second question: you should be able to pass all the parameters your Java library needs via command line parameters or a file (for example a JSON or XML file). It may get a bit complicated, so you should asses what's easier to do: call the Java code from Python or rewrite it in Python.

Comment: the data is not simple data.(not in table format) its actually read from the file and converted to objects and returned so that the user can access the data easily from the calling program. Writing that kind of data to a file again to be read by python is inefficient.

Comment: It can be done, and JSON seems like a good candidate for serializing objects in Java so they can be deserialized and used in Python. However, this kind of solution will give you some overhead, of course. So, again, you should consider: 1) sticking to Java, instead of Python, 2) rewriting your Java library in Python, 3) using Jython

Comment: 1) I just need the library to be accessible to python too, along with java.
2) That would be done as the last resort.
3) But i need the library to be accessed FROM python. Jython just has the python features and runs in a JVM right?

Comment: In this case I would recommend writing a command line Java program which calls the library with parameters passed as JSON in a file and returning results as JSON in a file as well. I know it sounds like quite a lot of work to do, but I don't see any easier way to do it. You can then easily write a Python function which would make calling this Java program easy, by converting keyword arguments to the input JSON format and deserializing output JSON and returning Python objects.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't learned how to create new instances of java class in a jar file by java constructors, but accidentally found that it's very easy to use any java static methods to access java objects in py2j.

step 1: download py4j zip file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py4j. "py4j0.10.0.jar" is in the zip file.

step 2: install py4j by

```
pip install 'D:\Downloads\py4j-0.10.0.zip'
```

step 3: add py4j0.10.0.jar as well as the_lib_you_use.jar (like owlapi-distribution-3.5.0.jar for the example below) to build path in your eclipse project

step 4: create AdditionApplication.java, and copy and paste the code of AdditionApplication.java at https://www.py4j.org/, and run Java application AdditionApplication.java

step 5: after running AdditoinApplication.java, test the example code in a python file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()                   # connect to the JVM

random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()   # create a java.util.Random instance
number1 = random.nextInt(10)              # call the Random.nextInt method
number2 = random.nextInt(10)
print(number1,number2)
(2, 7)
addition_app = gateway.entry_point        # get the AdditionApplication instance
addition_app.addition(number1,number2)    # call the addition method


Math = gateway.jvm.java.lang.Math
a = Math.max(4, 6);
print a

IRI = gateway.jvm.org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI

abcIRI = IRI.create('fewf#fe')
print 'abcIRi = ' + str(abcIRI)
print 'abcIRI.getFragment() = ' + abcIRI.getFragment()
```

The result on console is :

```
(5, 0)
6
abcIRi = fewf#fe
abcIRI.getFragment() = fe
```